# Trouble correlating SMTP logs in IIS with .NET application

Tags: .net, iis, smtp

We have a web application which sends out emails (who doesn't).

Recently we implemented something where a client can send out a questionnaire to their customers.  There may be thousands sent at a time.  (don't worry, it's not spam.  There's nothing being sold and it's just a bunch of questions)

We are running into issues where we're getting a lot of bounce backs for a lot of different reasons, most of which, I believe, are just your garden variety bad email address or mailbox full errors.  The company which I work for is worried that it's because of something we've set up.

The only way I have for diagnostics is to go into the log files for the large SMTP files and look up the address in question.  I have no way of knowing how many times an error happened, if there are errors we can avoid, etc.

Right now I log the email being sent but once it goes to the SMTP I lose any sort of context to it.  I guess what I am asking is, is there a technique or a better SMTP server or something we can utilize which helps us better understand our SMTP data, and ideally I can use it to tie back to when I sent it in code?

Currently I use the vanilla IIS SMTP in Windows Server 2008 and the .NET application doesn't have anything special going on other than it's .NET 3.5.  I am open to new SMTP server tools if need be.

Comment: "once it goes to the SMTP I lose any sort of context to it" - don't you have the SMTP message ID? I assume that'll get logged with any error? You can IIRC set IIS up to log to a database which you could then query after, but there'll always be an asynchronous component here. You could also try a third-party solution e.g. http://postmarkapp.com who will ping you back with a web request for bounces and errors etc.

Comment: There isn't an SMTP message ID as I see with the logs...  You can set up to a database but it's also not using an id. I'll do some research on postmarkapp.com.  Looks promising

Comment: Not knowing much abut this, could you add an SMTP event sink to capture the RFC822 message ID as it passes through the SMTP server & use it for later correlation? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894286

Answer (score 0):

You could set the System.Net.Mail.[MailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.deliverynotificationoptions.aspx&ei=zP16UO_sNsii2AXO_YCgDg&usg=AFQjCNHE9bqHLtnGWioANQ_-gIbCtqhRBA) to [DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.deliverynotificationoptions%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  This will send an email to the "From" address whenever delivery fails.

FYI, there have been reports that [DeliveryNotificationOptions may only work with Exchange server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800299/does-system-net-mail-deliverynotificationoptions-only-work-with-exchange).  With other mail servers, you may have to set the "Return-Receipt-To" SMTP value directly.