# How to get back DeliveryNotificationOptions in Message in c#?

Tags: c#, email, send

I created an application which sends mail but want to know if some of the mail has failed. How could I know that? I try to use code

```
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
```

but it just sends through my online mail delivery, I want to see those in application over the `Message.Show`. Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: Not sure how possible this is since bounce backs can take different periods of time.  You may be able to route bounce backs to a folder and monitor that folder.

Comment: It should be delivered via email, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800299/does-system-net-mail-deliverynotificationoptions-only-work-with-exchange

Comment: @shookdiesel yes but only problem is that i use online server like gmail, and hotmail ...